# Regex.IsMatch("Abcd", @"/^\S*$/"); returns false

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using C#. When I test this pattern at https://regexr.com/ it works but it doesn't work in my application.

I want to disallow whitespace in the input(username and password).

Comment: You may benefit from [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/` surrounding characters are delimiters for the regex itself -- for example, in javascript you can use those in place of quotes: `"Abcd".match(/^\S*$/)`

In C#, you must use quotes, so you can write your code simply as:

```
Regex.IsMatch("Abcd", @"^\S*$")
```